# Nginx reverse proxy for domain.com:port

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, sonarqube, reverse-proxy

I have a web application running and publicly available on `http://example.com:8099`

To run the application over HTTPS, the app [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/#header-5) suggests that we use a standard reverse proxy because it does not natively support HTTPS. All the guides I found is about proxying with just a domain root and does not take the port into consideration.

To begin with, I'm not sure which port should I even listen to in the first place. Is it **443**, or **8099**?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    error_log         /var/log/nginx/sonar-error.log;
    access_log        /var/log/nginx/sonar-access.log;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8099;
    }
}
```

In my server (AWS EC2 instance), the application is also running at the same port `http://localhost:8099` as in the domain.

I've tried different configurations and checked whether anything is logged in to these log files. But these were empty. So I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: Does your AWS Security group allow 443 port opened? Also, do you have SSL Certificate, to provide service via https?

Comment: @Grynets yes 443 is opened. I have no issue getting a certificate (preferably with certbot). What I'm not sure is the configuration required, and the port which I should listen to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen on port 443 (the port Nginx is allowing connections on), and `proxy_pass` to 8099 (the port application traffic is being passed to).

Your also need to ensure the `server_name` line contains the DNS name that traffic is being requested to, or is an an underscore inside speech marks (`"_"`) to ensure allrequests are matched to that server entry.